# MYSQL: Unclear syntax error when querying with REGEXP

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run a query on a mysql database with the query written as

```
sample = SentMessage.where("created_at > ? AND to REGEXP ?", 1.hour.ago, "^#{network.prefix}" )
```

However, I get an error

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'to RLIKE '^(25678|25677|25639)')' at line 1: SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `sent_messages` WHERE (created_at > '2017-01-30 11:00:37.781400'
>   AND to RLIKE '^(25678|25677|25639)')

Someone, please help point out this syntax error, cannot seem to find it after checking mysql documentation.

Comment: I think `to` is the column name.

Comment: Sorry realized that and removed comment just before yours.  I am wondering though if it is still the issue - reserved word maybe?

Comment: @rasmeister, it is not a reserved word!

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) it is. Check table 9.2.

Comment: You can quote it  - [see this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)